# Installed fonts not showing up, Linux Mint 15 64bit

Tags: linux-mint, x11, fonts, fontconfig

I'm trying to install these bitmap fonts: http://font.gohu.org/

I downloaded the compressed PCF files and extracted them to /usr/share/fonts, Then ran `sudo fc-cache -fv`.

The fonts weren't showing up in any program's font options.

I tried the same but with true type fonts; same result.

I tried using `~/.fonts` as my font directory; still no change

I tried using Mint's inbuilt font installer (by double clicking on the font file), and it says "Install Failed" when I click on the Install button. I've tried renaming the `.pcf.gz` files to .pcf but with the same results.

I tried doing all of the above and then rebooting my system and I still can't see the fonts in any programs.

Comment: Renamed the `.pcf.gz` files to `.pcf`? But that doesn't change the nature of the files -- they are still compressed.

Comment: I also use Mint, and I can't install these fonts, either. I used the Font Viewer to install them (both PCF and TTF), and they don't appear in the GTK font picker. EDIT: when it says it failed, that usually means the font has already been installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the default config restricts the use of bitmap fonts, that's all.

```
$ sudo rm /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf
$ sudo ln -s /etc/fonts/conf.avail/70-yes-bitmaps.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-yes-bitmaps.conf
```

restart X (i.e. log out and log in again) and you should be good to go :)

(note, however, that not every program can use bitmaps fonts.  LibreOffice, for example, can't use them.)

**edit:**

just for the record, and in case it wasn't clear, I'm running Linux Mint 15 64bit as my primary operating system, and I've successfully installed and am using the GohuFonts -- no need to `ungzip` them, or to use `xset`.

Comment: `xset` removes the need to restart the X server, if one doesn't want to close the session.

Comment: @peterph -- is that so?  thanks, I didn't know that!

Answer (score 2):

You need to recreate X server's font list. Either restart your X session (you can also start another one either on different virtual terminal or use a nested server like `Xephyr`) or simply tell the one running to reindex its font cache:

```
$ xset fp rehash
```

Comment: That should be `xset fp rehash`

Answer (score 0):

On KDE, the fonts I added to `~/.fonts` did not show up in programs until I ran `fc-cache -f -v`. I cannot imagine why. No such problems on GNOME.

Answer (score -2):

Don't forget to uncompress the download.

```
gunzip filename.pcf.gz
```